# Hibernate caching by example?

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache

Several cache-related Hibernate questions:

1. In L1 caching (session-based caching), as soon as the session closes the cache is dropped/cleared. But with L2 caching (application/global/distributed caching), when does the cache get dropped/cleared/flused? Is there a way to clear/flush the L2 cache manually/programmatically?
2. You can specify an `EhCacheCacheProvider` for the L2 cache. But EhCache requires an `ehcache.xml` config file on the runtime classpath to configure the caches. Are there specific names for the Hibernate L2 cache that I can use to fine-tune them in `ehcache.xml`?
3. If Program A is using a Hibernate-managed entity (some POJO in a persistent state), and is thus actively being managed/tracked by Hibernate, and a separate application (Program B) updates the same record - does Hibernate automatically update the in-memory POJO? For example, my `fizz.war` web app is connecting to a MySQL server and is managing a persistent `User` instance (which corresponds to the `users` table in MySQL). Currently, this User's email is `john.smith@example.com`. Then, at the same time, `buzz.war` (a different web app) updates the same `users` record's email to `jane.smith@example.com`. Does Hibernate automatically update the `User` instance to contain the update?

Comment: I found the answer to #2 (how to configure EhCache XML for use with Hibernate) here: [http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/hibernate](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/hibernate). Straight from that document: "*Hibernate creates caches named after the fully qualified name of Domain Objects. So, for example to create a cache for `com.somecompany.someproject.domain.Country` create a cache configuration entry similar to the following in ehcache.xml.*".

Comment: And here as well: [https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfigureEhcacheAsASecondLevelCache?_sscc=t](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfigureEhcacheAsASecondLevelCache?_sscc=t).

Answer (score 0):

For #1, couple of thoughts:

- Let underlying cache implementation (i.e. ehcache) do the eviction for you by using concepts such as time (timeToLive, TimeToIdle) or capacity (MaxelementInMemory) evictions...
- If using hibernate 3.x, you can access the evit*() method directly from the sessionFactory object.
- Or, if using Hibernate 4.x, you can use the evict*() methods as part of the org.hibernate.Cache Interface (the methods out of the SesisonFactory are still there...but deprecated)(http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Cache.html#evictEntity(java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable)...So for example, to evict all the entities from a cache region:

  sessionFactory.getCache().evictEntityRegion(entitClass);
- Finally, *much* more tied to the underlying Cache implementation (hence not quite recommended): you can get a handle on the ehcache CacheManager object (usually a singleton) and then evict entries that way...

  CacheManager.getInstance().clearAll();

or

```
//remove things from a specific cache
CacheManager.getInstance().getCache("cache").remove();
```

For #3, no, hibernate will not know if the underlying DB backend is being updated by another app (and hence will not be able to clear the l2 cache for that entity that was externally updated)...which goes back to #1...you'll need to intelligently clear the L2 cache from a buzz.war entity update (if you're using distributed caching such as ehcache + terracotta, that could be possible...)

Hope that helps.